# Scale column of a table in percentage of \textwidth

Tags: tables

If I make different tables on one page, it doesn't always look as good as I wanted. The biggest problem is that some tables are wider then other.
Therefore I would like to control the columns of a tables in function of the text width, so it would always be even width. 
Is there an option to do something like this:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{10%}|p{30%}|p{30%}|p{30%}|} 
\hline
A & B & C & D \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `p{.1\textwidth}` but when adding up you need to take account of `\tabcolsep` space either side of teh column, ans `\arrayrulewidth` for the rules (if  you use `array`  package)

Comment: Your example does certainly not compile. `tabular`, not `tabluar` and it's open-ended ;-)

Comment: and contains `%` inside the code.

Comment: @sigur yes I know the % will not work, therefore my question ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Package `tabularx` can help in calculating the column widths.
There are four columns, which should fill the available space (`\linewidth`).
Then the column specification using `X` columns is given in the following example. Package `tabularx` takes care of `\tabcolsep` and the width of the vertical rules, if it calculates the column width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
    |>{\hsize=.4\hsize}X|% 10% of 4\hsize 
    >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|% 30% of 4\hsize
    >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|% 30% of 4\hsize 
    >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|% 30% of 4\hsize
       % sum=4.0\hsize for 4 columns
  }
    \hline
    A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Solution without package `tabularx`

The problem can be solved with simple `p`-columns:

- LaTeX adds width `\tabcolsep` to the left and right of a column by default.
- Vertical lines have width `\arrayrulesep` if package `array` is loaded (the packages is often implicitly loaded by other packages). Otherwise, the contribution to the table width is zero.

The following example first calculates the net table width for the columns for use in the `p-columns`. The calculation is done with e-TeX's `\dimexpr`. Alternatively, package `calc` with `\setlength` can be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newdimen\NetTableWidth

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \NetTableWidth=\dimexpr
    \linewidth
    - 8\tabcolsep
    - 5\arrayrulewidth % if package array is loaded
  \relax
  \begin{tabular}{%
    |p{.1\NetTableWidth}|%
    p{.3\NetTableWidth}|%
    p{.3\NetTableWidth}|%
    p{.3\NetTableWidth}|%
  }
    \hline
    A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a good reason to want to achieve the same using something other than tabularx though. I've just found out that tabularx can't display verbatim environments (such as minted).

Comment: @ZachSmith Added solution without package `tabularx`.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this thread looking for a solution without `tabluarx`.
I didn't want to use another extra package as proposed in the solution by Heiko.

Here is my alternative solution **that does not require any additional package**. I included multi-column cells to highlight the relative width of the columns, meaning in this use case you don't want to manually set the width of each column, but in relation to other columns, while using the percentage of `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\width}
\width.1\linewidth
\begin{table} [h!]
    \centering\begin{tabular}{|p{\width}|p{\width}|p{\width}|p{\width}|p{\width}|p{\width}|p{\width}|}
        \hline
        Num & A & B & C & D & E & F  \\\hline
        1 & 1A & 1B & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1CD} &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1EF} \\\hline
        2 & 2A & 2B & 2C & 2D &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2EF} \\\hline
        3 & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{3ABCDEF} \\\hline
        4 & 4A & 4B & 4C &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{4DEF} \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot of a table with multi-column cells]

Comment: This does not work though, your table is more than 70% of the linewidth, you can see this by adding more columns for instance. This is because, as the other answer correctly accounts for, every cell wall gets left and right a bit of space added to it.