# How to make tikzpicture fill whole tabular cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have set up a a `tabular` environment and inside of it a `tikzpicture`. How can I adjust the width to the table cell?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % DIN A4

\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, top=25mm, bottom=20mm, right=25mm, left=25mm]{geometry} % Seitenränder
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} % Mathematische Symbole

\usepackage{tabularx} % Tabellen
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Funktionsgraph
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\title{Exponential- und Logartihmusfunktion im Vergleich}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}

\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin = -10, xmax = 10, ymin = -10, ymax = 10, xtick distance = 2, ytick distance = 2, xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty, grid = both,    minor tick num = 1, major grid style = {lightgray}, minor grid style = {lightgray!25}, width = 0.5\textwidth, height = 0.5\textwidth,axis lines = middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$, legend style={at={(0.025,0.025)},anchor=south west}, legend cell align={left}]
        \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thick,blue,grid=major] {2^x)};
        \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thin,black,grid=major] {x};
    \addlegendentry{$2^x$}
        \addlegendentry{$x$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin = -10, xmax = 10, ymin = -10, ymax = 10, xtick distance = 2, ytick distance = 2, xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty, grid = both,    minor tick num = 1, major grid style = {lightgray}, minor grid style = {lightgray!25}, width = 0.5\textwidth, height = 0.5\textwidth,axis lines = middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$, legend style={at={(0.025,0.025)},anchor=south west}, legend cell align={left}]
        \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thick,red,grid=major] {log2(x))};
        \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thin,black,grid=major] {x};
    \addlegendentry{$log_2(x)$}
        \addlegendentry{$x$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

side question: Why do I have to use `X` for `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}`?

Comment: You don't "have to" use X with tabularx, but that is kind of the point of using tabularx, to have control over which columns can stretch out and which don't (if you put X the column can stretch, if you put something else, i.e. l, r, or c, it won't). If you don't need that don't use tabularx.

Comment: Please can you put your minimal working example to compile it? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Plergux thank you, the documentation handed to me didnt't include that

Comment: @Sebastiano Done, thank you

Comment: I think you would be better off if you were using `groupplots` from `pgfplots` instead of a `tabular`.

Comment: @user238301 That sounds very good.

Comment: It's your 7th question now it's time to read and understand https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 for your future questions.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `tabularx` you need to use at least one column of type `X`, otherwise it will not work properly. In your case I would adopt `tikzpicture` width to width of table cell and instead of `X` column types use `C` derivate from `X` as `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % DIN A4
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, 
            top=25mm, bottom=20mm, hmargin=25mm]{geometry} % Seitenränder
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} % Mathematische Symbole

\usepackage{tabularx} % Tabellen
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Funktionsgraph
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\title{Exponential- und Logartihmusfunktion im Vergleich}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begingroup
\pgfplotsset{
    xmin = -10, xmax = 10,
    ymin = -10, ymax = 10,
    xtick distance = 2,
    ytick distance = 2,
    xticklabel=\empty,
    yticklabel=\empty,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
    width = \linewidth,
    height = 0.5\textwidth,
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    legend pos=north west
            }
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|}
    \hline
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thick,blue] {2^x)};
\addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 2,smooth,thin,black] {x};
    \legend{$2^x$, $x$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    &   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thick,red] {log2(x))};
    \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 2,smooth,thin,black] {x};
    \legend{$\log_2(x)$, $x$}
    \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}       \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you can adopt cell width to width of `tikzpicture` by use simple `tabular`:

```
\begin{center}
\pgfplotsset{
    xmin = -10, xmax = 10,
    ymin = -10, ymax = 10,
    xtick distance = 2,
    ytick distance = 2,
    xticklabel=\empty,
    yticklabel=\empty,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
    width = 0.5\textwidth,  % <---
    height = 0.5\textwidth,
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    legend pos=north west
            }
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
 % ...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
I wonder, why you use table at all, Both images you can draw in parallel without it as ˙groupplot`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % DIN A4
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait,
            top=25mm, bottom=20mm, hmargin=25mm]{geometry} % Seitenränder

\usepackage{pgfplots} % Funktionsgraph
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\title{Exponential- und Logartihmusfunktion im Vergleich}
\author{me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style = {
        group size=2 by 1,
        horizontal sep=1em,
                  },
    xmin = -10, xmax = 10,
    ymin = -10, ymax = 10,
    xtick distance = 2,
    ytick distance = 2,
    xticklabel=\empty,
    yticklabel=\empty,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
    width  = 0.5\textwidth,  
    height = 0.5\textwidth,
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    legend pos=north west
                ]
\nextgroupplot
    \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thick,blue] {2^x)};
    \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 2,smooth,thin,black] {x};
    \legend{$2^x$, $x$}
\nextgroupplot
     \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thick,red] {log2(x))};
    \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 2,smooth,thin,black] {x};
    \legend{$\log_2(x)$, $x$}
\end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: groupplot]

Comment: +1: Very good! :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, thank you very much!. +1 for your answer too (good explanation).

Answer (score 4):

- I converted your code into a more practical minimal working example.
- I used [Scale column of a table in percentage of \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249040) for constructing the table.
- For me, it looks ok now.
- **Question to the pros:** I tried to center the cells using [Centering in tabularx and X columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89166) (adding `\centering` to the column definition) but I could not figure out how to do it. Maybe you can give it a try.
- Regarding the accuracy of the width, please see [pgfplots: how can I scale to text width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36297/).

> Since pgfplots doesn't use the exact space, you could make it fit
> using \resizebox of graphicx:
>
> ```
> \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
> \begin{tikzpicture}%
> ...
> \end{tikzpicture}}
> ```

- [pgfplots: how can I scale to text width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36297) also led to a new package called [tikzscale](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale).

---

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249040
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
|>{\hsize=1\hsize}X|% 50% of 2\hsize 
 >{\hsize=1\hsize}X|% 50% of 2\hsize
   % sum=2.0\hsize for 2 columns
}
\hline
% <-- Left Cell Begins
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$},
            width=0.50\textwidth,
        ]
        % use TeX as calculator:
        \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
& % <-- Next Cell
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$},
            width=0.50\textwidth,
        ]
        % use TeX as calculator:
        \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\\ % <-- End of Row
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update:

It looks like `width=1\linewidth,` is even better than `width=0.5\textwidth,`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
|>{\hsize=1\hsize}X|% 50% of 2\hsize 
 >{\hsize=1\hsize}X|% 50% of 2\hsize
   % sum=2.0\hsize for 2 columns
}
\hline
% <-- Left Cell Begins
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$},
            width=1\linewidth,
        ]
        % use TeX as calculator:
        \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
& % <-- Next Cell
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$},
            width=1\linewidth,
        ]
        % use TeX as calculator:
        \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\\ % <-- End of Row
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As you ask me (in comment below my answer): advantages of `tabularx` (in short) is ability to calculate table columns width. FOr this you need to prescribe width of table and use at least one  `X` column type. Later is actually `p{<calculated width>}` column. These widths you can change with ratios between column width: `\hsize=<ratio>\hsize`, where you need to take a care that sum of ratios is equal to number of `X` columns. In OP case you not need to declare ratios between column widths since images have equal width.

Comment: @zarko thanks, that is helpful

Answer (score 3):

While this does not technically answer the question, in general the `groupplots` library is a very good tool to arrange several plots relative to each other. Among other things this also allows you to draw the table lines with Ti*k*Z, which offers more control and variations.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % DIN A4

\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, top=25mm, bottom=20mm, right=25mm, left=25mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} % Mathematische Symbole

\usepackage{tabularx} % Tabellen
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Funktionsgraph
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\title{Exponential- und Logartihmusfunktion im Vergleich}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1,
                 horizontal sep=2ex},%<-adjust
                 xmin = -10, xmax = 10, ymin = -10, ymax = 10, 
                 xtick distance =2, ytick distance = 2, 
                 xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty, grid = both,
                 minor tick num = 1, major grid style = {lightgray}, 
                 minor grid style ={lightgray!25}, 
                 axis lines =middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$, 
                 legend style={at={(0.025,0.025)},anchor=south west}, 
                 legend cell align={left},
                 height=7cm,width=8cm,
                 no markers
                 ]
     \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thick,blue,grid=major] {2^x)};
        \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thin,black,grid=major] {x};
        \addlegendentry{$2^x$}
        \addlegendentry{$x$}
     \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thick,red,grid=major] {log2(x))};
        \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 200,smooth,thin,black,grid=major] {x};
        \addlegendentry{$\log_2(x)$}
        \addlegendentry{$x$}
    \end{groupplot}
    \path (group c1r1.east) -- coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux)
     (group c2r1.west);
    \draw ([xshift=-0.5ex,yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.south west)
     coordinate (sw)
     rectangle ([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=0.5ex]current bounding box.north east)
     coordinate (ne) (aux|-sw) -- (aux|-ne);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]