Understanding tabularx hsize specifications for extendable columns with relative sizings: Why ">{\hsize=.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X"?
According to the official tabularx documentation, to size extendable X columns relative to each other, a preamble argument like this can be used:
{>{\hsize=.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X
>{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}

This will make the second column 3 times as large as the first column.
However, according to this and this, a simpler version like this can be used:
{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X|
>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|}

Why does the official documentation add \linewidth=\hsize? Does it multiply by linewidth and assign hsize to what exactly?
Here is a MWE for both methods:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\section{width=linewidth}

% from tabularx documentation, section 4.3
\noindent{}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|}
    \hline
    \the\hsize & \the\hsize\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249043/7892
\noindent{}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
|>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X|% 25% of 2\hsize 
>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|% 75% of 2\hsize
   % sum=2.0\hsize for 2 columns
}
\hline
\the\hsize & \the\hsize \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\section{width=0.5*linewidth}

% from tabularx documentation, section 4.3
\noindent{}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|}
    \hline
    \the\hsize & \the\hsize\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249043/7892
\noindent{}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{
|>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X|% 25% of 2\hsize 
>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|% 75% of 2\hsize
   % sum=2.0\hsize for 2 columns
}
\hline
\the\hsize & \the\hsize \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}

And the output from the MWE:


"[These instructions] will make the second column 3 times as large as the first column." A slight qualification: The instructions will make the usable width of the second column 3 times as large as the usable width of the first column. The key to understanding the distinction between usable width and total width of a cell is that the latter includes the whitespace padding (usually in the amount of \tabcolsep) that LaTeX inserts automatically on either side of the usable portion of the cell.

An example is worth a thousand words.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
  |>{\hsize=.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|
  >{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|
}
    \hline
    Something &
    Something
    \begin{itemize}
      \item aaaaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk llll mmm nnn
      \item aaaaa bbb ccc ddd
      \item aaaaa bbb ccc ddd
      \item aaaaa bbb ccc ddd
    \end{itemize}
    Something \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
  |>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X|% 25% of 2\hsize 
  >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|% 75% of 2\hsize
}
\hline
    Something &
    Something
    \begin{itemize}
      \item aaaaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk llll mmm nnn
      \item aaaaa bbb ccc ddd
      \item aaaaa bbb ccc ddd
      \item aaaaa bbb ccc ddd
    \end{itemize}
    Something \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}


Do you see the problem? As long as you use nothing that relies on \linewidth there's no difference, but lists do rely on \linewidth.
By the way, if you define a macro such as
\newcommand{\colfrac}[1]{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}

you can simplify the code for the first environment (the correct one) into
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\colfrac{0.5}}X|>{\colfrac{1.5}}X|}


Thanks. So \linewidth=\hsize resets \linewidth. How come it manages to reset it to the original \hsize and not the just modified one? How does LaTeX know how to separate assignments like that, i.e. A=BC=D into A=B and C=D, instead of reading it as A=B*C=B*D for example?

@KIAaze \hsize is used internally in order to do computations. But as soon as a cell starts up, \hsize has again the value it has outside the tabularx. LaTeX doesn't use \hsize directly. For the second question, \hsize=0.5\hsize is already a complete assignment and what comes along cannot influence it.
